# Change from update-alternatives command not taking effect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, alternatives

I tried to change my PHP CLI version with `sudo update-alternatives --config php`:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.1      81        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/php8.0.15   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php8.1      81        manual mode
```

I set it to 0 and checked it with `update-alternatives --display php`:

```
php - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/php8.1
  link currently points to /usr/bin/php8.1
  link php is /usr/bin/php
  slave php.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
/usr/bin/php8.0.15 - priority 1
/usr/bin/php8.1 - priority 81
  slave php.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/php8.1.1.gz
```

It looks like it worked, but if I check it with `php -v` then I get:

```
PHP 8.0.15 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 10:21:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.15, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

`command -v php` outputs `/usr/local/bin/php`.

---

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You presumably have `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, and since there’s a `php` binary in `/usr/local/bin`, your shell uses that. The `php` alternative configured by `update-alternatives` ends up having no effect — at least, on anything based on that `PATH`.

To fix this, in your case, I recommend removing the PHP installation in `/usr/local`. A simpler approach would be to re-order your `PATH`, but that might affect other binaries you rely on in `/usr/local/bin`.